# What the difference with using double quotes for searching words in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to find the documentation about what the difference double quotes will make in queries like this.

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "Name:\"something\" AND ObjecId:\"else\"",
    "analyze_wildcard": false
}


"query_string": {
    "query": "Name: something AND ObjecId: else",
    "analyze_wildcard": false
}
```

I found in documentation that if a phrase is double-quoted then the whole phrase will be queried. But in my query, I am using a single word/value instead of the phrase. Can you point me to the documentation section where this behaviour described.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Using " means exact match (not case sensitive though)

In your case, it should not have a impact as you are using single word.

Comment: I am not sure what part of document I need check, I can see this
> The query string is parsed into a series of terms and operators. A term can be a single word — quick or brown — or a phrase, surrounded by double quotes — "quick brown" — which searches for all the words in the phrase, in the same order.
But I think this does not match my case - I don't use a phrase.

Comment: it is a phrase for elastic ... of one word. Elastic does not check if your phrase is a grammatically correct sentence.